# getting error when using nuxt 3 with nuxt auth module

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth

I am using nuxt 3 + nuxt auth module

getting this error :

[image]

this is my nuxt config

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
      ],
      auth: {
        strategies: {
            cookie: {
              cookie: {
                // (optional) If set, we check this cookie existence for loggedIn check
                name: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
              },
              endpoints: {
                // (optional) If set, we send a get request to this endpoint before login
                csrf: {
                  url: ''
                }
              }
            },
          }
      }
})
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

The auth module is currently not supported by Nuxt3 but it is planned on the roadmap.
https://v3.nuxtjs.org/community/roadmap#%EF%B8%8F-roadmap

Latest official update: https://twitter.com/Atinux/status/1570317156033642496?t=YNN0iWL6M5l3Z0xm_ernCg&s=19